# how can I run my hello world application on black berry

Tags: blackberry

can I run my black berry sample application on device with account at app world

Answer (score 1):

Bug Finder is right u can upload ur app on the blackberry device but please ensure that if it uses any signed API then you must sign your application before installation.

But i believe that sample app wont be using any signed API.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your application to your blackberry either using the Blackberry desktop software, or, get hold of the javaloader, and upload it that way

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload the OTA of it to your webhost and access it on your BlackBerry. And as others said you might have to sign it depending on your code.

For more information on keys look at http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp